# Android ListView customizada em um fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment

Tenho um aplicativo cujo *layout* foi feito em `tabs` e em uma delas gostaria de implementar o `ListView`customizado, porém não consegui pois a classe JAVA da `tab` estende a classe `fragment` e para fazer a *list* preciso estender a classe `ListActivity`, como no JAVA não existe herança múltipla, não sei como fazer.

Gostaria de saber se é possível implementar um `ListView` customizado em um *layout* do tipo `fragment`?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta é sim. Existem diversas maneiras de você resolver isso e se o problema é o `ListActivity` então você pode usar o [`ListFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

Veja mais [aqui na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância, mas ao invés de estender fragment devo estender ListFragment?

Comment: Sim Adriano, você pode extender ListFragment.